# How to transform a bunch of nodes in to a table

Tags: xml, xslt

I have something like this:

```
<root>
   <elementA></elementA>
   <elementB></elementB>

   <elementC>Some Data 1</elementC>
   <elementC>Some Data 2</elementC>
   <elementC>Some Data 3</elementC>

   <elementD></elementD>

   <elementC>Other Data 1</elementC>
   <elementC>Other Data 2</elementC>
   <elementC>Other Data 3</elementC>
</root>
```

and I need something like this:

```
<root>
   <elementA></elementA>
   <elementB></elementB>

   <wraper_for_C>
      <elementC>Some Data 1</elementC>
      <elementC>Some Data 2</elementC>
      <elementC>Some Data 3</elementC>
   <wrapper_for_C>

   <elementD></elementD>

   <wraper_for_C>
      <elementC>Other Data 1</elementC>
      <elementC>Other Data 2</elementC>
      <elementC>Other Data 3</elementC>
   <wrapper_for_C>
</root>
```

Does someone know how to get a wraper around a block of elements with same name?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 here?

Comment: Yes I think I'm able to use XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can make use of [xsl:for-each-group](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html) using its `group-adjacent` attribute, to group adjacent elements with the same name.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count(current-group()) > 1">
            <xsl:element name="Wrapper_{name()}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to dynamically create the wrapper element name based on the grouped element name.

Comment: Huges thanks to Tim C :)
You have realy helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template to copy all nodes and templates -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- but do nothing with element that is directly preceded by the element with the same name -->
  <xsl:template match="*[name() = name(preceding-sibling::*[1])]"/>

  <!-- template for the first element of group -->
  <xsl:template match="*[not(name() = name(preceding-sibling::*[1]))][name() = name(following-sibling::*[1])]">
    <xsl:element name="wrapper_for_{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="c"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- template for element that copies current element and processes next element in group --> 
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="c">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]" mode="c"/>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

p.s. I was wrong, I thought that it's all about C element :)